# Разница между mouseleave и mouseout jquery

Tags: jquery

Какая разница между mouseleave и mouseout?

Comment: [mouseleave and mouseout are similar but differ in that mouseleave does not bubble and mouseout does.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave ........ можно было как ответ написать (имхо это более наглядно, чем в ссылке от Grundy в доках), но слишком он уж большой получается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в доках как раз нагляднее :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Разница событий заключается в том, что событие *mouseout* всплывает, а *mouseleave* - нет](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Это означает, что обработчик *mouseout* стоящий на контейнере будет ловить события *mouseout* от дочерних элементов, в то время как *mouseleave* - только от текущего элемента.

Пример ниже показывает это поведение: лог с mouseout будет появляться, при уходе с любого элемента, в то время как mouseleave - Только при выходе за границы контейнера, на котором и висит обработчик.

```js
document.getElementById('root').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  console.log('mouseleave', e.target.id);
});

document.getElementById('root').addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  console.log('mouseout', e.target.id);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#root {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  Root block
  <div id="a">
    A block
    <div id="b">
      B block
      <div id="c">C block</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link