# Как навести на меню в oncontextmenu?

Tags: javascript

Хочу скрыть дефолтное поведение браузера при клике правой кнопки в определённом блоке.

Всё срабатывает как надо кроме того что надо скрыть меню просто выходя из родителя но так же иметь возможность кликать по ссылкам внутри этого контекстного меню ..

Тренировался здесь: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NVKLjY

Вот в этом месте я завис

Как надо поступить в этом случае ?

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".block"),
    init =  document.querySelector(".init"),
    body = document.querySelector("body");

parent.oncontextmenu = function (){
  init.style.display = "block";
  return false;
}

body.onmouseover = function (){
  init.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.block{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
}

.init,.view{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  display:none;
}
.init a,
.view a{
  color: #fff;
 }

.view{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="init">
     <a href="#">Какая то ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Разница между mouseleave и mouseout jquery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/725989/186999)

Comment: @Grundy  при ....out так же не могу навести на меню

Comment: `body.onmouseover` убрал?

Comment: @Grundy  дай ответом отмечу решением

Comment: сам пиши как сделал:-)

Comment: @Grundy да неее ..так ни честно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала написал с проверками, а потом подсмотрел в комментах от @Grundy про [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event), забыл про него совсем

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".block"),
    init =  document.querySelector(".init"),
    body = document.querySelector("body");

parent.oncontextmenu = function (){
  init.style.display = "block";
  return false;
}

parent.onmouseleave = function (){
  init.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.block{
  width:500px;
  height:150px;
  background:wheat;
  position: relative;
}

.init{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background:lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="init">
     <a href="#">Какая то ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что там делает (e)  ?

Comment: @MaximLensky рудимент =)